# APDU commands for card personalisation

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, apdu, mifare

I'm trying to execute a simple `CommitPerso` APDU command

```
  String APDU_COMMAND =
                              "90" // CLA  90h
                                    + " 01" // INS (command for writePerso (01h sample data for privacy))
                                    + " 00" // P1: 00h
                                    + " 00" // P2: 00h
                                    + " 10" // Lc: Length of data field (10h = 16 bytes = 1 block)
                                    + " 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08" // String of data units to be written
                                    + " 00"; // Le: 00h
```

I'm getting `62531` response code. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
I am using Mifare Plus SE 1K cards and Pinetree reader which supports Mifare PLUS cards. I'm using SDK provided by the same reader called SmartPeak following way to sent APDU commands:

```
mMifareCardReader.transmitRawCmd(inBuf, rspBuf)
```

The response of this will be `int`.

Comment: Without information, what card you have (Mifare? which?), it is difficult to give a useful answer. Your response code (is it given in hexadecimal?)  does not help either... For Mifare cards the used reader  may be helpful too.

Comment: @guidot edited question with card, reader and SDK information. Thanks!

Comment: @guidot I'm wondering if you can help me thanks!

Comment: I have no documentation concerning `CommitPerso`. If it works like other Mifare write commands, P1=P2=0 corresponds to the first block, which can't be written normally.

Comment: These commands are generally handled using hexadecimals, i.e. F443 in this case. What is a "Pinetree reader"? Do you have a link?

Comment: @FajarKhan -  were you able to find a successful solution? I am also try to find sl1 to sl3. it would be great if you can help